# SharePoint permissions

Tags: list, permissions, custom-list, versioning

I'm customizing a custom list form using SharePoint Designer 2010. The idea of this custom list is user can edit the default list and edit the content and submit the page for site owners approval, till then the page should be in draft version. Next, once the user submits the edited page the site owner has to get an alert message saying that someone has edited the page, the site owner has to review the page and publish/reject the submitted content. Its all about version. The problem here is, when user submits the content he/she getting  error message. I gave the user permission as "Member" "Contributor" these permission levels are not working. Only if i give "Full Control" it works. But, it should not be like that.

Can any one please advice. Sorry if i am not clear, i can explain again.

Regards,
SM, Saravanan

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that whatever permission levels you assign to the user it should have Version related permissions checked in the permission level.

Typically they are - Open Versions , View Versions and Delete Versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the level of Contribute  : Can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents.

Approve : Can edit and approve pages, list items, and documents.

so you give approve permissions, contribute don't have permissions to approve page.